# how to open a infowindow with a button inside a infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a button that sits inside the infowindow, opening another infowindow with different content, I already put the button inside the infowindow ..
I just need to make the button open another infowindow.

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.729981,-63.878333),      
      icon:  predio});


    var contentimage = '</br> <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Fotos"/></div><</div><div><img src="images/gardenclub.png" width="460" height="240"/>'




           var infowindow    =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:contentimage
      })
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        infowindow.open(map,marker); });



  var btn1=document.getElementById('btn1');    
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn1, 'click', function(){
```

I'm stuck here ..

appreciate the help

Comment: 'Another infowindow' - you mean have two visible at the same time, on different locations?  Or swap the content of the first infowindow (in effect closing this infowindow and opening another on the same marker)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_geodesic_proj.html

One infowindow with link to the next, if you click on the link, it opens the "next" infowindow.

No reason the link couldn't be a button.

Comment: hello guys, i have lots of content to show in only one infowindow.. i want a button inside that infowindow to open another infowindow into the same marker showing another content, like, when open shows some text and when click in the button show pictures in other window.. thanks for answer quiclky